# Slicing an array and string

Tags: go

For below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    // Declare a string with both chinese and english characters
    s := "世界 means world"

    // UTFMax is 4 -- up to 4 bytes per encoded rune
    var buf [utf8.UTFMax]byte

    fmt.Println(len(buf))
    fmt.Println(cap(buf))
    // Iterate over the string
    for i, r := range s {

        // Capture the number of bytes for this rune
        rl := utf8.RuneLen(r)
        fmt.Println("Rune lenght is:", rl)

        // Calculate the slice offset for the bytes associated
        // with this rune
        si := i + rl
        fmt.Println("Index is:", i)
        fmt.Println("Slice offset:", si)

        //Copy of rune from the string to buffer
        copy(buf[:], s[i:si])

        // Display the details
        fmt.Printf("%2d: %q; codepoint: %#6x; encoded bytes: %#v\n", i, r, r, buf[:rl])
    }

}
```

---

Built-in functions `len` & `cap` give the value for array type `[4]byte`

```
var buf [utf8.UTFMax]byte

fmt.Println(len(buf))
fmt.Println(cap(buf))
....
copy(buf[:], s[i:si])
```

Q1) Does `buf[:]` create a new slice header that points to array storage `buf`?

Q2) Is `len(buf)` performing implicit conversion of `buf` from array type to slice type?

Q3) Does `s[i:si]` create a new slice header that points to string `s`?

Comment: Yes, No, No. All three questions are obvious from the language spec (e.g. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity and https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions), and https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro . Instead of wild guesses and complicated experiments I'd like to encourage reading the official documentation. Unlike other languages the Go spec is very understandable.

Comment: @Volker this is not wild guess... Am going thru a training, above is a sample code from the training. I couldn't manage completing spec in parallel, will take time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buf[:]` is a slice whose cap and len are the length of the array, and the backing store is the array `buf`.

`len(buf)` gets the length of the array. It does not convert `buf` to a slice to do that. Length of `buf` is fixed at compile time.

`s[i:si]` creates a new string, not a new slice.

Comment: What about `cap(buf)`? I mean, why `cap()` is allowed on array type?

Comment: The language spec says: The expressions len(s) and cap(s) are constants if the type of s is an array or pointer to an array...

Comment: When you say "`buf[:]` is a slice ", Does `buf[:]` create a new slice header(ptr,length,cap) backing an existing array `buf`?

Comment: Yes, `buf[:]` is a slice header with the backing array `buf`

Comment: Can I say above code can be replaced with single line `runtime.stringtoslicebyte()`  to convert string(`s`) to slice byte?

Comment: If you want to convert a string to a byte slice, use `[]byte(s)`. `stringtoslicebyte` is an internal function.

Comment: Is `r` a rune literal with 3 bytes(`世`) in first iteration? in the above code... What is the memory representation of `r`?

Comment: A rune is an int32. The iteration goes like (0,世) (3,界), etc.